# Rails undefined method `sanitize_sql_array' for ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recently re-installed my operating system on my work machine, pulled my existing Ruby on Rails project, and received the following error on a certain page of my application:

```
undefined method `sanitize_sql_array' for #<Property::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb0c1780630>
Did you mean?  sanitize_for_mass_assignment
```

I'm not sure what the issue is being caused by, I cannot find any information on it.

The offending line is apparently `count_data = @properties.group_by_month('properties.created_at', format: "%b %Y").size`

Where `@properties` is an ActiveRecord_Relation.

I am running on Rails version `5.1.6.1`, and ruby `2.4.1`.

The `group_by_month` method is provided by the [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem

Any ideas on what this issue is caused by? 
Please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Update:

I've figured out the problem. I did not install mysql timezone support, which caused the groupdate gem to create an error. The most recent version of the gem fails to notify you in the error to install timezone support like previous versions did.

Comment: If the version of rails is identical it's worth checking that you're still using the same ruby version as you were before. If both of those are the same then there should be no new code errors like the one you pasted above.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention I am using ruby 2.4.1 which is the same as I used before. That's what makes the problem so confusing for me

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29507 - the last comment suggests the sanitize_sql_array method was made public in Rails 5.2. I'd suggest changing the rails version to match this, upgrade to that version, and then trying again

Comment: @MatthewWeeks, it would be great if you add the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my orginal post:

> I've figured out the problem. I did not install mysql timezone
>   support, which caused the groupdate gem to create an error. The most
>   recent version of the gem fails to notify you in the error to install
>   timezone support like previous versions did.